# Dudas sobre limpiar buffer en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una función que lee un nombre, si el nombre es nuevo lo guarda en una estructura de datos y si el nombre está repetido vuelve a pedir el nombre. (Tengo otras funciones iguales a esta, pero esta es la única que utilza **getline(cin, variable)**

```
void anombre(){
    cout << "Nombre: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, nombre);
    if(!agenda.vnombre(nombre))
        anombre();
}
```

Mi problema es que esta función sólo funciona una vez; suponiendo que ya tengo almacenado el nombre "Mariana" al llamar la función el programa se vería así:

```
Nombre: Mariana
Nombre: Mariana
Telefono:
```

Siendo **Teléfono:** el mensaje de la siguiente función para pedir los datos, es decir, **anombre()** sólo negó el nombre repetido una sola vez y pasó a la siguiente función. Al pasar esto se almacena una string vacía y eso se va a mi estructura.

La función **agenda.vnombre(nombre)** es la siguiente:

```
bool vnombre(string& n){
    for(int i = 0; i < tamano(); ++i){
        if(n == contactos[i].nombre) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Las demás funciones son básicamente iguales, sólo cambia el tipo de dato que va a comprobar: contactos[i].telefono, contactos[i].correo, etc.

¿Cuál es mi error? Tengo entendido que es parte de limpiar el buffer de cin para que esto funcione correctamente. (Esto no sucede con las otras funciones para pedir datos como teléfono, correo electrónico, edad, etc).

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el contenido de `vnombre`?

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo.

Comment: `cin.ignore();` elimina el primer carácter de lo escrito, reemplazalo por  `cin.ignore(0,'\n');` y ve si te funciona.

Comment: Gracias. Ya lo sustituí en la función pero se salta la función del nombre y pasa directamente a la del teléfono, así queda la consola    Nombre: Telefono:

Comment: Creo que deberías leer la documentación de cin, ignore y getline, porque estás confundiendo sus funciones. Cuando dices `Mi problema es que esta función sólo funciona una vez; suponiendo que ya tengo almacenado el nombre "Mariana" ...` ¿Cómo es que has almacenado ese nombre? El código que muestras podría almacenar "ariana", no "Mariana".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La firma de la función `cin.ignore()` es :

```
istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);
```

Es decir, si tu realizas la llamada:

```
cin.ignore();
```

Estás eliminando a lo sumo un carácter del buffer. Esto está lejos del objetivo que pretendes que es limpiar el buffer de entrada. Una de las formas más habituales para limpiar el buffer es

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max());
```

`std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` indica el número más alto para el tipo `size_t`, un alias que en 32 bits suele ser equivalente a `unsigned int`. La instrucción anterior, en resumen, intenta descartar todo el contenido del buffer de entrada.

Por otro lado, la función `getline` se encarga de eliminar el delimitador del buffer de entrada. Si partes de un buffer limpio, la llamada a `getline` va a dejar el buffer igualmente limpio. Es decir, llamar a la función `ignore` de forma recursiva no es necesario e incluso puede resultar contraproducente.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
void anombre(){
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<size_t>::max());
  do
  {
    cout << "Nombre: ";
    getline(cin, nombre);
  } while (!agenda.vnombre(nombre));
}
```

Te ahorras las llamadas recursivas (que no son necesarias) y evitas limpiar el buffer cuando no es necesario.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Esto me funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: @eferion; no quisiera sonar rudo, pero todos (cada uno) de los puntos de tu explicación están errados. `Llamas a cin.ignore, supongamos que se limpia el buffer y se reestablecen los bits de error.`No es correcto; si la entrada es "Mariana", cin.ignore() sólo extraerá la 'M', y quedará "ariana". Y tampoco hay ninguna razón para que se restablezcan bits de error.(puedes consultar http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). `Se almacena Mariana en el buffer de entrada.` No, en todo caso se almacenará "ariana". `...se activa el bit EOF`Tampoco hay razón para eso. Revisa por favor...

Comment: @asdasdasd No es ser rudo. Si algo no es correcto o no está bien explicado lo suyo es mejorarlo. En la primera llamada a `cin.ignore` asumo que el buffer está vacío. Si el buffer de entrada tuviese más de un carácter la lectura del primer elemento fallaría. En cuanto a lo demás lo miraré con tranquilidad. Hace más de 4 años que no programo en consola y podría haberme equivocado con las explicaciones.